# Is there any tool or way to obfuscate structured text?

Tags: plc, st

I am looking for a tool to obfuscate structured text code written for PLC. both paid or opensource. i cannot find anything in google. Please help.

Comment: By obfuscate do you mean translate into another language like ladder?

Comment: No, i mean it shall not be easily readable to understand the logic.

Comment: Why? Couldn't you just create a library that is compiled and no one will see your code.